# How can I "install" a driver for a USB-to-Serial adapter?

Tags: drivers, usb

I have a USB-to-Serial adapter, Belkin F5U109, that I need to use with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I have found what appears to be a compatible driver, umct.4freebsd.gz (found here:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man4/umct.4freebsd.html).  It says to "place" some "lines in your kernel configuration file."

Being an absolute novice to Ubuntu, I have no clue how to do this, and I can't find anything in layman's terms instructing me on the procedure.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?  Thanks!

Comment: The link you provided is to a man page.  The download is the source of that man page.  The man page itself describes a driver for freebsd.  Using the adapter doesn't work out of the box and create `/dev/ttyyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyACM0`, or similar files?

Comment: Can you please post the dmesg command output, by the time you plug the adapter in to your PC. Have you tried to load the usbserial kernel module? modprobe usbserial By loading this module the kernel should create a virtual device node (e.g /dev/ttyUSB0) which you will be able to handle it as a serial port.

Answer (score -3):

It means you need to find the kernel configuration file. You can open it with

```
leafpad /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

Then add the lines you require.

Please note though, that messing around in the kernel files is not a good idea.

Comment: Why `leafpad` and why not `sudo` and why `\`uname -r\`` instead of `$(uname -r)`

Comment: That file is automatically generated, documenting the config of the kernel, editing it will not change the configuration.

Comment: @A.B. why not `leafpad`? There's nothing wrong with  \`uname\` instead of `$(uname)`. Sudo is indeed required but also kind of obvious. The only real issue is that the OP here does not explain that once the config file is modified, the kernel needs to be recompiled for it to make a difference. _That's_ a problem, not the choice of editor or preferred syntax!